# How to copy worksheet from one book to another

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to copy an existing sheet from one workbook to a new book. I use the sheet to make pivot tables that are in weekly reports. So in this case, I am trying to move a sheet called "Accounts" from Book1 to Book2.

This is my code so far:

```
sheets("Accounts").copy before :=workbooks("Book2").sheets("Sales")
```

I am getting the out of range error, I am assuming because I don't specify where the "Accounts" sheet is coming from, however I have been unable to find proper answers from Google.

I have a line of code that I used previously to copy a range:

```
workbooks("Book1").worksheets("Sales").range("range").copy
```

I don't know if that code would apply to the problem at hand, but if it does please let me know.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: `Workbooks("Book1").sheets("Accounts").Activate // Workbooks("Book1").sheets("Accounts").copy before:=workbooks("Book2").sheets("Sales")`?  (Where `//` means a line break)

Comment: @BruceWayne, unfortunately, this code gives me a 438 error, object doesn't support property or method. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you change the remove the // ?

Comment: What line, the `Activate` or the next one? Also, the workbook name is correct in your code, yes?

Comment: yes, @braX and I make sure to get the names correct as well